# Create an Admin Module (Maybe?) on Ionic3 App?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to create an admin-module-like for my app. Something like, when an admin logs in, can add material to the app. Other people (usual users) can only see that material and use some functionalities. The admin account has more buttons to interact with and another interface (maybe?).

Some ideas or help with this?
Thanks a lot.

I'm using Ionic3 and Firebase.

Comment: This is something of a broad question to ask here. My answer down below is what I usually do when I want to make an admin-only area. There are many ways to implement that, though, and therefore your question wouldn't have a proper "correct answer" (unless someone managed to list every single way to do it... Which is unlikely).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simplest solution (probably not the safest, though) would be to use a flag (as in, a boolean value stored in the user's data in your database) that determines whether an user is an admin or not and then just check that flag whenever you want to show or hide something from your users.

As a recommended security measure, make sure to also use Firebase's rules to guarantee only users flagged as "admin" can make certain changes in the database. It would also be a good idea to have a node to store all the admin's User IDs - although the most secure way of going about that is by adding those UIDs manually through the Firebase console (therefore allowing the node itself to be read-only for everyone).

Comment: Yep, was thinking around it and found that using ng-if* to hide the admin functions from the users based on this flag in firebase should do the trick. Thanks for help.